# Admin CSS/JS change path from http to https manualy

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml

I have a problem with SSL and I need to modify manually the admin CSS/JS paths from **`HTTP to HTTPS`**, was looking for the corresponding files for days now... But with no luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried everything from the guides and other questions and nothing worked for me.

Thanks,

Comment: have use https for admin pages?

Comment: Yes, I set everything to YES, use for Unsecure, secure, frontend, backend, then rewrited url's to SSL and everything is working, but the styles and script's of the Admin are not loaded because they are still beeing called from HTTP and not HTTPS

Comment: Have you cleared CSS/JAVASCRIPT caches??

Comment: I cleared all the var/cache (manually, to make sure it's 100% empty). Or those are saved in other place?

Comment: Have you tried merging or demerging (depending on its current state) the JS and CSS files, then flushing var/cache?